# Clear cache of pages in ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

When try to show a page twice the previous page show at the second time.The ionViewWillEnter() function is not working second time

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: i tried to use ion-tabs,there is three tab contain in the ion-tabs.The tabs page is opened from another page, then go back to the first page again open the tabs page.But the previous data of tabs page is loaded.i have passes the tabs page with different value only the first time the page opened correctly then pass some other value to the ion-tabs it will not get updated